# Change root to user#show after log in

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise, routes

I cant seem to get the root to change in my Rails 4 application. I simply want the root to change once a user logs in, so that it points to the user show page.

I get the following error:

**Couldn't find User without an ID**

My routes.rb looks like so:

```
devise_for :users, :path_names => {:sign_up => "register", } 

  authenticated :user do
    root to: "users#show", as: :authenticated_root
 end

  unauthenticated do
    get 'welcome/index'
    root to: "static#index"
  end

  match 'users/:id' => 'users#show', as: :user, via: :get

   get "/asian-century" => "static#asian-century"
   get "/pricing" => "static#about"
   get "/about" => "static#pricing"
   get "/chatroom" => "static#chatroom"
```

My users controller likes like so:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_user, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  def index
    @users = User.all
  end

  def show
     if params[:id]
        @user = User.find(params[:id])
     else
        @user = current_user
     end
     @userlessons = @user.lessons_to_attend.where("starts_at > ?", Time.now.advance(:hours => -1)).order(starts_at: :asc)

     unless @user == current_user
        redirect_to :back, :alert => "Access denied."
     end
  end

private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def user_params
      params[:user]
    end
end
 ...
```

Where am I going wrong here? I have looked at multiple solutions to this problem and I can't seem to find an answer.

EDIT:

Error in terminal:

```
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-07 14:03:27 +0800
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = 1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
Processing by UsersController#show as HTML
Completed 404 Not Found in 1ms

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound - Couldn't find User without an ID:
  activerecord (4.1.1) lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:402:in `find_with_ids'
  activerecord (4.1.1) lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:68:in `find'
  activerecord (4.1.1) lib/active_record/querying.rb:3:in `find'
   () Users/Dizzy/Documents/MM/mandarinminds/app/controllers/users_controller.rb:77:in `set_user'
  activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:424:in `block in make_lambda'
  activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:143:in `block in halting_and_conditional'
  activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
```

Comment: Can you post the full error stacktrace?

Comment: @Pavan does that help? New edit.

Comment: Yes.Can you post your `set_user` method of your controller?